# Android - With Room, deleting items db does not work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

In a project using Room, I am testing the different methods of a dao object. The tests for inserting and retrieving items work, only the test for deleting items does not work.

After deleting some items the numbers of items retrieved (with `getAll`) is the same as before calling the `delete` function.

The entity is:

```kotlin
@TypeConverters(TagConverters::class)
@Entity(
    tableName = "tag",
    indices = [ // Enforce tag_name to be unique
        Index(value = ["tag_name"], unique = true)
    ]
)
data class TagEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "tag_id") val id: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tag_name") val name: TagName,
    val icon: String? = null,
    val color: String? = null
)
```

The Dao is the following:

```kotlin
@Dao
interface TagDao : BaseDao<TagEntity> {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM tag WHERE tag_id = :id")
    suspend fun getById(id: Long): TagEntity

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tag WHERE tag_name = :name")
    suspend fun getByName(name: String): TagEntity

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tag")
    suspend fun getAll(): List<TagEntity>

    /**
    Some stuff that I have tested
    @Delete
    override suspend fun delete(vararg theme: ThemeEntity)
    @Query("DELETE FROM theme WHERE theme_id  LIKE :id")
    */

    @Query("DELETE FROM tag WHERE tag_name = :id")
    suspend fun deleteById(id: Long)
}
```

And BaseDao is:

```kotlin
@Dao
interface BaseDao<T> {
    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(obj: T): Long

    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(vararg obj: T)

    @Upsert
    suspend fun upsert(vararg obj: T)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(obj: T)
}
```

My test is:

```kotlin
class TagDaoTest {
    private lateinit var database: AppDatabase
    private lateinit var tagDao: TagDao

    @Before
    fun createDb() {
        val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
        database = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(
            context, AppDatabase::class.java
        ).build()

        tagDao = database.tagDao()
    }

    @Test
    fun tagDao_delete_a_tag() = runTest {
        val tag0 = newTag(name = TagName("HISTORY"))
        val tag1 = newTag(name = TagName("Science"))
        val tag2 = newTag(name = TagName("Nature"))
        val tag3 = newTag(name = TagName("Sport"))
        val tag4 = newTag(name = TagName("culture"))

        tagDao.insert(tag0)
        tagDao.insert(tag1)
        tagDao.insert(tag2)
        tagDao.insert(tag3)
        tagDao.insert(tag4)

        val retrievedTags = tagDao.getAll()
        Assert.assertEquals(5, retrievedTags.size)

        tagDao.delete(tag1)
        tagDao.deleteById(tag2.id)

        val retrievedTags2 = tagDao.getAll()
        Assert.assertEquals(3, retrievedTags2.size)
    }
}

private fun newTag(
    name: TagName,
    date: LocalDate = LocalDate(year= 1979, monthNumber= 11, dayOfMonth = 25)
) = TagEntity(
    name = name,
    icon = null,
    color = null)
```

The error is the following:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<3> but was:<5>
at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:835)
at eu.aklal.app.core.database.TagDaoTest$tagDao_delete_a_tag$1.invokeSuspend(TagDaoTest.kt:93)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at eu.aklal.app.core.database.TagDaoTest.tagDao_delete_a_tag(TagDaoTest.kt:73)
```

I have tested some advices found on Stackoverflow, they did not help.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Looks like you are mixing tag name and tag ID in the delete method.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `@Query("DELETE FROM tag WHERE tag_id = :id")` (i.e. `tag_name` changed to `tag_id`).

- `DELETE` doesn't mind if the WHERE clause result in now rows being found to be deleted.
- you were saying something along the lines of `DELETE FROM tag where 'fred' = 1`  (where for example a row had a tage_name of fred, the next might be bert ....)
- Only if you had a tag with the name 1 (or whatever id was passed) would the row be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I  have found my errors.

1. As @dev.bmax and @MikeT spotted it there is a typo in the declaration of the `deleteById`
2. I tried to delete the object that I have instantiated not the one that has been inserted.

The code works if I do what follows:

```kotlin
@Test
fun tagDao_delete_one_tags() = runTest {
    val tag0 = newTag(name = TagName("HISTORY"))
    tagDao.insert(tag0)

    val retrievedTagsFromDb = tagDao.getAll()
    Assert.assertEquals(1, retrievedTagsFromDb.size)
  
    /* WRONG: tagDao.deleteOneTag(tag0) //Trying to delete a local tag not one from the Db*/

    /* CORRECT: Retrieve a tag from the db */
    val tagRetrievedFromDb = retrievedTagsFromDb.first() 
    /* and remove it */
    tagDao.deleteOneTag(tagRetrievedFromDb)

    val retrievedTags1 = tagDao.getAll()
    Assert.assertEquals(0, retrievedTags1.size)
}
```